# new (ptr) T() == static_cast<T*>(ptr)?

Tags: c++, standards

I want to implement something like rust's dyn trait(I know this doesn't work for multiple inheritance)

> ```
> template<template<typename> typename Trait>
> class Dyn
> {
>     struct _SizeCaler:Trait<void>{ void* _p;};
>     char _buffer[sizeof(_SizeCaler)];
> public:
>     template<typename T>
>     Dyn(T* value){
>         static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Trait<void>,Trait<T>>
>             ,"error Trait T,is not derive from trait<void>"
>         );
>
>         static_assert(sizeof(_buffer) >= sizeof(Trait<T>)
>             ,"different vtable imple cause insufficient cache"
>         );
>
>         new (_buffer)Trait<T>{value}; 
>     }
>     Trait<void>* operator->(){
>         return static_cast<Trait<void>*>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(_buffer));
>     }
> };
>
> template<template<typename> typename Trait,typename T>
> struct DynBase:Trait<void>
> {
> protected:
>     T* self;
> public:
>     DynBase(T* value):self(value){}
> };
>
> struct Point{
>     double x,y;
> };
>
> struct Rect{
>     Point m_leftDown,m_rightUp;
>     Rect(Point p1,Point p2){
>         m_leftDown = Point{std::min(p1.x,p2.x),std::min(p1.y,p2.y)}; 
>         m_rightUp = Point{std::max(p1.x,p2.x),std::max(p1.y,p2.y)}; 
>     }
> };
>
> template<typename = void>
> struct Shape;
>
> template<>
> struct Shape<void>
> {
>     virtual double area() = 0;
> };
>
> template<>
> struct Shape<Rect> final
>     :DynBase<Shape,Rect>
> {
>     using DynBase<Shape,Rect>::DynBase;
>     double area() override{
>         return (self->m_rightUp.x - self->m_leftDown.x )
>             * (self->m_rightUp.y - self->m_leftDown.y);
>     }
> };
>
> void printShape(Dyn<Shape> ptr)
> {
>     std::cout << ptr->area();
> }
>
> int main()
> {
>     Rect r{{1,2},{3,4}};
>     printShape(&r);
> }
> ```

but I found that the c++standard may not be able to derive “new (ptr) T() == static_cast<T*>(ptr)“?
So conversely, “static_cast<T*>(ptr) == new (ptr) T()” cannot prove

```
Trait<void>* operator->(){ return static_cast<Trait<void>*>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(_buffer)); }
```

Other attempts

a abstruct class can't be a union member(why?),and I can't use placement new to calculate offset at compile time, because Trait is an abstract class.

So does the standard specify the validity of static_cast<T*>(ptr) == new (ptr) T()?

Comment: `char _buffer[sizeof(_SizeCaler)];` should be aligned to `Trait<T>`

Comment: This is a good question. The equality is often assumed, but I'm curious if it is guaranteed. Consider adding the `language-lawyer` tag for standard-oriented answers.

Comment: template Dyn can't get any infomation of T,it needs to type erase T with no performance penalty

Comment: You can't get type erasure without a performance penalty.

Comment: An abstract class can't be a member of any other type.  Nothing special there about unions.

Comment: I should say no additional performance penalty rather than no performance penalty, which is my expression problem

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: The rules for `operator new()` forbid overhead (which implies the pointer is returned with zero offset), while `operator new[]` allows overhead, which is almost always at the beginning of the allocation thus requiring an offset.  It creates a bit of conundrum for placement `operator new[]`.  I think this was recognized as a defect and may have been fixed.

Comment: @BenVoigt My concern was with safely derived pointers. But I looked into it and in C++23 that won't be a thing anymore, and no mainstream compiler cares about that. So it isn't really an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expressions `new (ptr) T()` and `static_cast<T*>(ptr)`, where `ptr` has type `void*`, will return the same address, `ptr` (as long as `T` is a scalar type -- array types are allowed to have overhead when dynamically allocated)

However, the semantics are quite different.

- In `new (ptr) T()`, a new object of type `T` is created at the specified address.  Any prior value is lost.
- In `static_cast<T*>(ptr)`, there must already be an object of type `T` at the specified address, or else you are setting yourself up to violate the strict aliasing rule.

---

If `ptr` had a type other than `void*`, it would need to be related to `T` by inheritance or trivial adjustments (such as changing signedness or adding `const` or `volatile`), and the address might have an offset applied as a result of multiple inheritance.  But that will never happen in the code of this question.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: I said "the expressions will return the same address"

Comment: The possibility of array overhead has been removed for the non-allocating `new` via defect report with [CWG 2382](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2382.html).

Comment: emm，I know The standard states that void* operator new(size_t ,void* ptr) will return ptr without change，but  new (ptr) T() return a T* pointer ,not a void*.That may mean they are different?

Comment: @余国良 `void* operator new(size_t ,void* ptr)` is the allocation function. `new (ptr) T()` is a new expression. A new expression calls one allocation function to get storage, then causes the object's constructor to be to run using that storage for the object, then returns a pointer to that object. Placement new expression uses that non-allocating allocation function to just get the pointer back.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux,Because they are different expressions, the "no pointer changes" constraint on the former may not be passed to the latter？

Comment: @余国良 I believe that the guarantee is transitive, I don't think the object can be placed at an offset to that pointer. Otherwise it becomes impossible to know how large the storage you need to give to placement `new` actually has to be. This was the problem mentioned in this answer related to using placement new with arrays. But I am completely certain.

Comment: In pure implementation terms, this can be done.Place the virtual table in the ptr position and return the position after the virtual table.

There is no offset for either the static_cast of void* or T*. This implementation pattern seems to conform to all c++ standards? But my Dyn implementation will have problems

Comment: @余国良 The `Trait<T>*` must share the same address as `_buffer`. That is required by the standard as explained in this answer. But the `Trait<void>*` subobject may generally be offset from that, precisely because of the space required for the derived object's vtable pointer. The pointer returned by `new` cannot point past the vtable pointer, because the address of an object must be to the first byte of storage occupied by the object.

Comment: @user17732522
Can you give me a link to this description ?(“The Trait<T>* must share the same address as _buffe”)

Comment: @余国良 It is not written out anywhere explicitly. It is a consequence of the new expression being required to obtain only `sizeof(Trait<T>)` memory from `operator new`, so there is no possibility for an offset to place the object and as I said the address of an object is always to the first byte of storage occupied by it. But basically https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#16.sentence-2 is the relevant part.

Comment: @user17732522 ,And it isn't. If the standard does not specify it, putting the virtual table in front of the pointer is a feasible implementation when the Trait is a type that contains virtual functions. This does not affect the sizeof assignment, but requires an offset to be performed when the Trait pointer is returned after new

Comment: @余国良 No, that is not a valid implementation. https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#intro.object-9.sentence-1 requires that the address of the object is the address of the first byte occupied by it. The memory used for the vtable pointer is part of the object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249119/discussion-between--and-user17732522).

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not `new (ptr) T() == static_cast<T*>(ptr)` is true is not your actual problem.

The actual problem is that the class `Trait<T>` you are constructing is not standard-layout and as a consequence the `Trait<void>` subobject of the `Trait<T>` object is neither pointer-interconvertible with the `Trait<T>` object, nor does it have to be located at the same address. As a consequence you can't cast from `_buffer` to `Trait<void>*` without knowing `T` or having a pointer to `Trait<void>` specifically.

In other words, you need to store an additional pointer `Trait<void>*` in the class which you initialize from the result of `new (_buffer)Trait<T>{value};` (via implicit conversion), or alternatively at least an offset between `Trait<T>` and its `Trait<void>` subobject. (In the latter case beware that you need to add a `std::launder` after the `reinterpret_cast`.)

Furthmore, as mentioned in the comments, you need to assure that the buffer is suitably aligned for an object of type `Trait<T>`. That requires adding an `alignas` on the buffer so that it is suitable for all `T` you want to consider and then there should probably be a `static_assert` on the alignment analogous to the one for size as well.

---

Also, `static_cast<Trait<void>*>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(_buffer))` is equivalent to `reinterpret_cast<Trait<void>*>(_buffer)`. No need for the double cast.

Comment: Whether there is a difference between two casts and one cast depends on the implementation?if static_cast<T*> will have offset.In addition, this implementation is assumed to be based on single inheritance

Comment: @余国良 `static_cast` from `Trait<void>*` to `Trait<T>*` generally has an offset, but the cast between `void*` and `Trait<T>*` (or `Trait<void>*` or any other object pointer type for that matter) never has.

Answer (score 0):

Other question:

> an abstract class can't be a union member(why?)

because it makes no sense to have an abstract class as a union member.  In order to use a union member, you need to instantiate an object of the union member's type to store in the union.  But you can't instantiate an object of an abstract class, so you could never use the abstract class union member for anything.

Comment: but This will provide a relatively safe transition from buffer to Trait<void>

Comment: @余国良 It does not. `union` can't be use for type erasure or type conversion in C++. Reading from a `union` member which wasn't the last one to be assigned to is UB in C++.